# Possible cofinalities of cuts of ultraproducts

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, ultrafilters, pcf-theory

Suppose $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, $\bar{\mu}=(\mu_i: i<\kappa)$ is an increasing sequence of regular cardinals ($>\kappa$) and set

$pcut(\bar \mu)=\{ (\lambda_1, \lambda_2):$ for some ultrafilter $D$ on $\kappa$, we have    $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$     is the cofinality of  a cut of $\prod_{i<\kappa}\mu_i/D       \}$.

Clearly $|pcut(\bar \mu)| \leq 2^{2^\kappa}.$

> **Question.** Are there any non-trivial bounds on $|pcut(\bar \mu)|,$ in particular are there bounds similar to Shelah's pcf theory for this notion?

**Remark 1.** If $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) \in pcut(\bar \mu),$ then $\lambda_2 \leq 2^\kappa.$ To see this, suppose not and let $(\bar \mu^\xi=(\mu^\xi_i: I<\kappa): \xi < (2^\kappa)^+)$ be a $<_D$-decreasing sequence. Define $F: [(2^\kappa)^+]^2 \to \kappa$ by

$F(\xi, \zeta) = \min\{ i<\kappa: \mu^\zeta_i < \mu^\xi_i     \}$.

By the Erdos-Rado partition theorem one can find some $X$ of size $\kappa^+$ and $i_* < \kappa$ such that for all $\xi < \zeta$ in $X$, we have $\mu^\zeta_{i_*} < \mu^\xi_{i_*} $
and we get a contradiction.

Also, it seems reasonable (though I don't have a proof) to use results of pcf theory to show that $|\{\lambda_1: (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) \in pcut(\bar \mu)     \}|\leq 2^\kappa$.
and hence get $| pcut(\bar \mu) |\leq 2^\kappa$.